# Observing Android LiveData<T> from ViewModel Return NULL

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-viewmodel, android-livedata-transformations

I have a `ViewModel` which handle showing `transactions` and `transactionSummary` LiveData

```
// Transactions
val transactions: LiveData<List<Transaction>> = getTransactionByDateUseCase
    .getTransactionsByDate(dateRange.startDate, dateRange.endDate)

// Transaction Summary
private var _transactionsSummary = MutableLiveData<TransactionSummary>()
val transactionsSummary: LiveData<TransactionSummary> = _transactionsSummary
```

The `transactions` come from *Room* which return `LiveData<T>` similarly in `transactionSummary` but there is transformation process to get the transaction's summary as `income` and `expense`.

Below is the transformation process:

```
private fun getTransactionsSummary(dateRange: DateRange): LiveData<TransactionSummary> {
    return Transformations.map(
        getTransactionByDateUseCase.getTransactionsByDate(dateRange.startDate, dateRange.endDate)
    ) { data ->
        getTransactionSummaryUseCase.transactions = data
        val summary = getTransactionSummaryUseCase.getSummaries(dateRange)
        summary
    }
}
```

However, when I request update from my Fragment the `transactionSummary` is always return `NULL`

`getFetchTransactionViewModel().updateTransactionSummary(selectedDateRange)`

Here is my update function inside `ViewModel`:

```
fun updateTransactionSummary(dateRange: DateRange) {
    _transactionsSummary.value = getTransactionsSummary(dateRange).value
}
```

I observe the `transactionSummary` like this:

```kotlin
    getFetchTransactionViewModel().transactionsSummary.observe(this, Observer {
            textViewIncome.text = it.totalIncome.formatCurrency(isVisibleCurrency = true)
            textViewExpense.text = it.totalExpense.formatCurrency(isVisibleCurrency = true)
            textViewBalance.text = (it.totalIncome - it.totalExpense).formatCurrency(isVisibleCurrency = true)
    })
```

Are there any missing steps or incorrect implementations?

Thank you

Comment: `_transactionsSummary.value = getTransactionsSummary(dateRange).value` <- this is what `map` is for

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into exactly the same problem, myself. It seems that LiveData objects created with Transformations.map (and probably MediatorLiveData in general) initialize their value only after the first observer subscribed to them (active state). Before that, even if the source LiveData has a value, it returns the value null (inactive state). That's happening in your function `updateTransactionSummary()`.

Solution 1: You could use the transformed LiveData directly instead of trying to extract the value from it and put it into another MutableLiveData. Something like this:

```
private var _transactionsSummary = getTransactionsSummary(dateRange)
val transactionsSummary: LiveData<TransactionSummary> = _transactionsSummary
```

Then you won't need the `updateTransactionSummary()` function.

Also, you can use the transactions LiveData directly as the source of the transformation instead of getting a second one:

```
private fun getTransactionsSummary(dateRange: DateRange): LiveData<TransactionSummary> {
    return Transformations.map(transactions) { data ->
        getTransactionSummaryUseCase.transactions = data
        val summary = getTransactionSummaryUseCase.getSummaries(dateRange)
        summary
    }
}
```

Solution 2: In your comment you said you want to trigger the summary update by another event. In that case it seems superfluous to use the LiveData transformation:

```
private fun getTransactionsSummary(dateRange: DateRange): TransactionSummary {
   getTransactionSummaryUseCase.transactions = transaction.value
   return getTransactionSummaryUseCase.getSummaries(dateRange)
}

fun updateTransactionSummary(dateRange: DateRange) {
    _transactionsSummary.value = getTransactionsSummary(dateRange)
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you. Really appreciate the help. But I wonder, how i can tell the `ViewModel` to update the `transactionsSummary` based on event which triggered by the `View`? Cause i create the `updateTransactionSummary()` to handle those event.

Comment: @fanjavaid, I added a solution 2 to my answer to support that use case.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> fun updateTransactionSummary(dateRange: DateRange) {
>     _transactionsSummary.value = getTransactionsSummary(dateRange).value
> }
> ```

This is not the right way to use LiveData.

`DateRange` is also a mutable parameter that must be propagated to the asynchronous data loading as an input.

This means it must be enclosed in a `MutableLiveData<DateRange>`, and then `.switchMap`'d into the correct query results.

```
// Transaction Summary
//private var _transactionsSummary = MutableLiveData<TransactionSummary>()

private val dateRange = MutableLiveData<DateRange>()

val transactionsSummary: LiveData<TransactionSummary> = dateRange.switchMap { date ->
    getTransactionsSummary(dateRange)
}
```

There's a good chance that `DateRange` should not be forgotten across process death, in which case if `DateRange` is actually `Parcelable` or `Serializable`, then it should be auto-persisted to Bundle using the `SavedStateHandle` of a `ViewModel`, using `private val dateRange = savedStateHandle.getLiveData<DateRange>("dateRange")` if possible.